# Facing impediment in switching between the tabs

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am not able to switch between the tabs as shown in below pic. I am using cucumber framework.

[image]
the exception i am getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: 
Element <button class="btn btn-emp alignrightfromright" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">...</button> is not clickable at point (1275, 85)
```

Selenium method to click the tab is written as in the Professional_InfoPage Page

```
public void ClickProfTab() {
        log.info("Clicking on professional info tab....");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
          action.moveToElement(profTab).build().perform();
          profTab.click();
    }
```

Step definition class (Professional_infoSD.java)

```
@When("^click on the Professional information Form tab$")
    public void click_on_the_Professional_information_Form_tab() throws Throwable {
        professionalinfo= new Professional_InfoPage();
        professionalinfo.ClickProfTab();        
    }
```

Comment: There are multiple answers to the "element is not clickable at point" in SO. Pick anyone u like form here - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selenium+element+is+not+clickable+at+point

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 reasons to it:

1. The element is not visible, in that case you can scroll the element in view (up/down) using javascript code and then perform the action.

   `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;`
     `js.executeScript("scroll(200, 200)”);//example`
2. There is another element (form/div) overlaying the element you want to click. Please check if you are identifying the correct element. It might be possible that your locator is pointing to the element that is on the page below the Employee form.

Hope this helps.